# Checkout Page Street Custom Validation

Tags: magento2, checkout, validation, customer-address

I want to add validation to prevent code blocks or special characters like {}%.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**: To add custom validation on the checkout page, create a new JS mixin that extends `Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator` and create a plugin for `Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor` to declare the validation rule.

**Implementation**: Assume you named the vendor name `Vendor`, and the module name `Checkout` (You can change the vendor name and module name as you wish). Take the following steps:

Step 1: Create the registration.php file:
File path: `app/code/Vendor/Checkout/registration.php`

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Vendor_Checkout', __DIR__);
```

Step 2: Create the module.xml file:
File path: `app/code/Vendor/Checkout/etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Checkout">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
            <module name="Magento_Ui"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Step 3: Create the requirejs-config.js file.
File path: `app/code/Vendor/Checkout/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator': {
                'Vendor_Checkout/js/form/element/validator-rules-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Step 4: Create the validator-rules-minxin.js file:

File path: `app/code/Vendor/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/form/element/validator-rules-mixin.js`

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    /**
     * Validate that string has specific special characters
     * @param {String} value
     * @return {Boolean}
     */
    function validateSpecialCharacters(value) {
        return /^[^{}%]+$/.test(value);
    }

    return function (validator) {
        validator.addRule(
            'validate-special-characters',
            function (value) {
                if ($.mage.isEmptyNoTrim(value)) {
                    return true;
                }

                return validateSpecialCharacters(value);
            },
            $.mage.__('Please remove invalid characters: {}%')
        );

        return validator;
    };
});
```

Step 5: Create di.xml file:
File path: `app/code/Vendor/Checkout/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="ModifyCheckoutField" type="Vendor\Checkout\Plugin\ModifyCheckoutField"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Step 6: Create ModifyCheckoutField.php file.
File path: `app/code/Vendor/Checkout/Plugin/ModifyCheckoutField.php`

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Checkout\Plugin;

class ModifyCheckoutField
{
    /**
     * Modify checkout street field validation
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array $jsLayout
    ) {
        //Shipping Address
        if (isset(
            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']
        )) {
            $shippingAddressFieldset = &$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']
            ['shipping-step']['children'] ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'];
            $shippingAddressFieldset = $this->addValidationForFields($shippingAddressFieldset);
        }

        //Billing Address on payment method
        if (isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']
            ['children']['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'])) {
            $paymentList = $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']
            ['children']['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'];

            foreach ($paymentList as $key => $payment) {
                if (isset($payment['children']['form-fields']['children'])) {
                    $paymentsListFormFields = &$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']
                    ['children']['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']['payments-list']
                    ['children'][$key]['children']['form-fields']['children'];
                    $paymentsListFormFields = $this->addValidationForFields($paymentsListFormFields);
                }
            }
        }

        //Billing Address on payment page
        if (isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']
            ['children']['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children'])) {
            if (isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                ['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form']['children']['form-fields']
                ['children'])) {
                $billingAddressFormFormFields = &$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']
                ['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']['afterMethods']
                ['children']['billing-address-form']['children']['form-fields']['children'];
                $billingAddressFormFormFields = $this->addValidationForFields($billingAddressFormFormFields);
            }
        }

        return $jsLayout;
    }

    /**
     * @param $formFields
     * @return array
     */
    private function addValidationForFields($formFields): array
    {
        $formFields['street']['children'][0]['validation']['validate-special-characters'] = true;
        $formFields['street']['children'][1]['validation']['validate-special-characters'] = true;
        $formFields['street']['children'][2]['validation']['validate-special-characters'] = true;

        return $formFields;
    }
}
```

Step 7: Finally, run the `setup:upgrade` command to make your new module active, and then compile code, deploy static content:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Done.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried and Its not working. Validation class is not added to data bind and also any where.